# Rails Fixtures / Uncountable model name results in NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fixtures, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a model named EventSeries, which is the same singular as it is plural. I have added this in every way I can imagine to the inflector:

```
inflect.uncountable %w( fish sheep EventSeries event_series Series series )
```

I have an `event_series.yml` fixtures file within `spec/fixtures`. I have even tried adding:

```
_fixture:
  model_class: EventSeries
```

at the top of the yml file, but it does not help.

I have also tried changing change the filename to `event_serieses.yml` and call `event_serieses(:d30_short_series)`, and I get `NoMethodError undefined method event_serieses`.

I use RSpec for testing. In a system spec, I have the following declaration:

```
let(:subject_series) { event_series(:d30_short_series) }
```

When I run the spec, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `event_series' for <RSpec::MySpecFile>
```

I have many other models and this pattern works for every other model (using the plural version, like `users` or `events`), so I assume this is a pluralization issue. I've searched for answers and found [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29973), which indicates the problem can be solved by adding the model name to the inflector, but that has not helped in my case.

I've managed to get all the other inherent problems with uncountable names working; for example, my path helpers are all working properly and Rails find my view files as expected. But I haven't been able to solve this fixture problem.

Is there a way to point RSpec to the correct method to access my fixtures?

Using Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.6.0, and RSpec 3.8.

Comment: Not an answer, sorry, but FYI - Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.6.0 and minitest 5.11 - works fine, without any inflection needed.

Comment: @smathy Just to be sure, I removed the inflectors temporarily, but this did not help. So the problem may be specific to RSpec.

Comment: `inflect.uncountable(%w(equipment information rice money species series fish sheep jeans police))` Rails has `series` included by default.  I'm not sure the problem with RSpec, but EventSeries is properly inflected by default and you don't need to add anything.

Comment: Is `event_series` supposed to be the model `EventSeries` as a global? What are you expecting `event_series(:d30_short_series)` to do? For me it's unclear how things are connected, it seems that your assumption and solution is to apply inflection on a model that should be the same name as singular or plural, but what is the code doing without the fixes you implemented?

Comment: @DaniloCabello This app is using [Rails fixtures](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html), and `event_series` in this context is a reference to the Rails fixture file. For all other models, this syntax returns an item from the fixtures.yml. For example, `users(:admin_user)` returns a single record from the users fixture file. In this context, `event_series(:d30_short_series)` should return a single event_series from the `event_series.yml` file.

Comment: I see, this seems to be a case that needs debugging if you can build a minimum gist/repo with the failing spec I would happily debug it. I would start by trying to find a way to list the loaded fixtures during the execution of the spec and print that;  maybe also patch the fixture loader to print the paths that have been loaded to check if my `event_series.yml` file is there. If the global has not been defined most likely for some unknown reason the file is being skipped.

Comment: Sounds like you have a good handle on what might be the issue. Would you care to look at the [actual repo](https://github.com/SplitTime/OpenSplitTime)?

Comment: Can you not over ride the fixtures file name in the config or model ?the Path is editable  . Alternatively set the class in the fixture file ? .. _fixture:
  model_class: EventSeries

Comment: @StevenMoffat Per my question, I have tried adding the model class to the fixture file, and it makes no difference. And yes, I can change the filename to `event_serieses.yml` and call `event_serieses(:d30_short_series)`, and I get NoMethodError undefined method `event_serieses`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your open source project, it was simpler to investigate and solve the issue.

The problem with this [specific spec](https://github.com/SplitTime/OpenSplitTime/blob/e00d1344092f1cd1c41119a98e5f45ff7de14cef/spec/system/visit_event_series_spec.rb) is that the needed fixtures were not being loaded.

You have two options to solve this problem.

**Option 1**: Add `:event_series` to `config.global_fixtures` in your [`rails_helper.rb`](https://github.com/SplitTime/OpenSplitTime/blob/e00d1344092f1cd1c41119a98e5f45ff7de14cef/spec/rails_helper.rb#L51).

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.global_fixtures = :a, :event_series, ..., :n
```

**Option 2**: Load the fixture just on that spec [`visit_event_series_spec.rb`](https://github.com/SplitTime/OpenSplitTime/blob/master/spec/system/visit_event_series_spec.rb)

```rb
RSpec.describe 'visit an event series page' do
  fixtures :event_series

  let(:user) { users(:third_user) }
```

Then the spec will now fail but for different reasons:

```
Failures:

  1) visit an event series page when the user is a visitor when all categories are populated Visit the page
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_link(resource.send(attr), href: path)
       expected to find visible link "Dirty 30 Running" but there were no matches. Also found "Dirty 30 Running", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

Which I believe you have a better understanding than me of why the following event link is not being displayed on the page.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of this. I was so sure it was a pluralization problem I didn't even check the global fixtures. Thank you!